# LaTeX Report Template for Windows PdfTeX

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, templates, report, document-configuration

I am very novice in LaTeX and would like to make similar documents (template) like the one referenced [in the LaTeX template here](http://web.mit.edu/ir/mitx/course_reports/6.041x_course_report_1T2014.pdf).

I would like to place the header, footer as in the similar fashion and at the same time similar text fonts, text formatting, table, image caption and referencing (citation and hyperlinks).

It would be really kind if you assist me in this regard. The referencing portion preferably at the end of the article and you might add some suggestions about the placement as well. I would have added some sample code but I didn't because I am scared whether it will be a standard one to begin with. Thanks in advance and if you need further clarification I am willing to provide that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like yours are hard to answer, since they contain many different steps.

In *this* concrete case I would just ask the author of the document if he's willing to provide some details on how he made it. There's even an email address on the title page where *Questions should be adressed to*...

Comment: People are significantly less likely to answer questions when they have to start from scratch, especially when they concern very individual projects with lots of different aspects and little general appeal. It doesn't matter whether your code is any good or not. What matters is that you provide something for people to fiddle with. There's no guarantee you'll get an answer if you post code. And there's no guarantee you won't if you don't. But you are more likely to get answers if (1) you post code and (2) you break the question down into bits on specific topics. Different people answer then.

Comment: It is unlikely (but possible) that someone comes by this question and then produces a template that gives you exactly the output of the PDF you linked to above. It is a very specific problem with a (potentially) very long (rich) solution. As cfr mentions, questions that are about one specific (yet abstract and generally applicable) subject are more likely to get answered. I'm also confident that many of the steps needed to get the output you seek can be found here already.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Next time while I post a question I will surely put these things in my mind. May you guys suggest something based on the code sample below (provided by @ibrahimkbd). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I just added a sample code so that others can assist you further about this. 
[image: First Page] [image: 2nd Page]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red,  urlcolor=blue}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.00in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx,xcolor,colortbl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mdwlist}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}% Used to control the spacing at enumerate (eg publication)
    \usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
    \usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage


    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \setlength\headheight{26pt} %% just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
    % \rhead{{\color{blue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}


    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \pagestyle{fancy}% Set default page style to fancy
    \rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{Overleaf_Logo.png}}
    \lhead{6.041x: MITx Spring 2014 Course Report}
    \lfoot{irx@mit.edu}
    \rfoot{\emph{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}% Page X of Y in the footer (centered)

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ENABLES \textsc{} INSIDE \section{}
    \usepackage{sectsty} % Play with Section --> TextSc
    \allsectionsfont{\scshape} % Declar text will be in textsc font
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{hologo}



    \usepackage{lipsum}


    % and the actual content starts here
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    {\large \textsc{\textbf{MIT Institutional Research, Office of the Provost\\
    in conjunction with the\\
    MIT Office of Digital Learning}}}
    \end{center}


    \noindent
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{Overleaf_Logo.png}
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{TexLogo_O.png}\hfill
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{TexLogo.png}\\
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}



    \begin{center}
    \huge{6.041x: Introduction to Probability - The\\
    Science of Uncertainty\\
    MITx Spring 2014 Course Report}
    \end{center}

    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\vspace{2mm}

    \noindent\includegraphics[width=16cm]{Image.png}\\
    Report prepared by itutional Research, Office of the  Provost.Questions should be addressed to irx@mit.edu.\\

    \today

    \vspace{1cm}

    \lipsum


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample. I still need some other modification and trying to work on it by finding some solutions given in this site. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ibrahimkbd, I am curious about the varying heights of the small cap letters in the preview image. Is it an intentional effect?  I get (your code images commented out)[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DxZB3.png  Note the "with the" in particular.

Comment: I believe it was intentional . You can make such writeup using '\textsc' command.